# Why can't I attach my AD RMS server to my SharePoint 2010 server?

Tags: 2010, central-administration, information-management

In my SharePoint 2010 installation when I go to `Central Administration -> Security -> Configure information rights management`, select `Use the default RMS server specified in Active Directory` and click OK I get the following error:

> The required Windows Rights Management client is present but the
>   server refused access. If you are switching from one RMS server to a
>   different RMS server, be sure you have set up a trust relationship
>   between the two. IRM will not work until the server grants permission.

I've set up the AD RMS role on my machine running Windows Server 2008 R2, and near as I can tell everything *should* be working properly.  What's the problem here?

**Edit:** Wait, will AD RMS work if it's installed on the same machine as SharePoint?

Comment: Closed at request of original poster.

Answer (score 3):

Do the Central Administration Web Application have Read & Execute rights to the web service ServerCertification.asmx? If not, give the IIS Application Pool `Read & Execute` rights to the `ServerCertification.asmx`, usually located in the folder `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\_wmcs\Certification`

Comment: Already done, didn't help.

Comment: Did you use the DisableLoopbackCheck key?

Comment: @TrevorSeward - What is that?